# Yacc/Bison yyerror

Tags: c, parsing, bison, yacc

I'm trying to create my own errors, but apparently, envoking yyerror() is not enough to tell parser that there is an error. I made a little example to describe my problem better.
So here is a parser that must check if a statement is two numbers with comma between them. And numbers can not start with 0.

input for yacc:

```
%token DIGIT            

%{      
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
void yyerror(char *s);    
%}

%%
    list:    |
        list stat ';' {printf("The statement is correct!\n\n");} |
        list error ';' {printf("The statement is incorrect!\n\n");}

    stat:   number ',' number

    number: DIGIT {if ($1==0) yyerror("number starts with 0");} | 
        number DIGIT {$$ = $1*10+$2;}
%%
extern int linenum;
void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, " line %d: %s\n", linenum, s);
}
```

for lex:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
int linenum = 1;
%} 

%% 

[0-9]               {
                 yylval = yytext[0] - '0';
                 return DIGIT;
                }

[ \t\r]+            ;
\n                  ++linenum;
.               return(yytext[0]);
```

Input for the parser:

```
34, 43;
32,fs;
03, 23;
```

And here is the output:

```
The statement is correct!

 line 2: syntax error
The statement is incorrect!

 line 3: number starts with 0
The statement is correct!
```

Even though the error on the 3rd line is found, parsing still continues. How can I fix it?

Upd: the problem was solved by using YYERROR;

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stop after detecting one error (why?), just return from the production concerned.

By default it will perform error recovery.

Answer (score 0):

The parse is continuing because you have a rule with `error` in it, which is an error recovery rule that tells the parser how to recover from an error and continue.  If you don't *want* to continue after an error, remove the error recovery rule.  Then `yyparse` will immediately return (non-zero) after an error.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me `yyerror()` just prints the error message, but does not set an error state in the parser. Possibly you can modify syntax a bit?

lex:

```
0          {
             yylval = 0;
             return ZERO;
           }
[1-9]      {
             yylval = yytext[0] - '0';
             return DIGITNOZERO;
           }
```

yacc:

```
number: DIGITNOZERO | 
        number DIGITNOZERO  {$$ = $1*10+$2;} | 
        number ZERO {$$ = $1*10;}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't help since i still need to tell the parser about error somehow. But thank you anyway!

Comment: By the way, the problem was solved by using YYERROR like this: `number: DIGIT {if ($1==0) {yyerror("number starts with 0"); YYERROR;}}`

Comment: This kind of thing should certainly be done in the lexer, and it doesn't solve the problem. It's ridiculous to use shift-reduce parsing to implement `atoi()`.